# ContextBroker with 1.3.0 version does not start correctly

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying to start the CB from console with this config:

```
contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost mi_db_host -db orion -multiservice -t 0-255 -logLevel DEBUG
```

The CB is not started and this message is returned by console:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::MsgAssertionException'
>
> what():  wrong type for field ( 0 ) 3 != 2

Answer (score 1):

This is typically due to the migration procedure for Orion 1.3.0 has not been done. Please, have a look to [this piece of documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/admin/upgrading_crossing_1-3-0/index.html).

As mentioned in [Orion 1.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/1.3.0):

> Important note: the DB model has changes regarding the previous version. Thus, a migration procedure on existing data has to be applied (or DB has to be dropped), see details here [it referst to the link in the first paragraph of this answer]. Not applying this procedure could make CB to crash.

Another solution is just to drop the orion DB... although doing so you will lost existing data, of course.